# Executing Jar with "java -jar executable.jar" is OK but even with execution permission, "./executable.jar" returns a "Bad Magic Number"

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a small application that I build with maven :

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>be.scripts.batchconverter.MainScript</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-executale-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>batchconverter</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I can run it with "java -jar batchconverter", but when I try to execute it with "chmod +x batchconverter.jar" and then "./batchconverter.jar", I got this generic error :

```
invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error
```

My JDK is oracle, "1.8.0_121", I have binfmt-support installed, and I'm running an ubuntu 16.04

Here is the manifest :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: jschoreels
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Main-Class: be.scripts.batchconverter.MainScript
```

And the ls result (to prove the x permission)

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jschoreels jschoreels 4,9M Mär  7 11:40 batchconverter.jar
```

Any idea to determine the cause ?

Comment: I think you can just execute other langs like bash,C/C++ instead you can write an execute script execute.sh with the content  java -jar ex.jar and then chmod a+x execute.sh so ./execute.sh might work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most file formats start with a fixed combination of bytes, or "magic number".
Java class files for example start with the bytes or "magic number" 0xcafebabe.

Your system needs to be able to recognize the type of file and know what to execute the file with.
Your system doesn't know how to directly execute jar archives, and it is atypical for unix systems to be configured to do so.

On ubuntu it is [possible to enable this with the binfmt-support package.](https://askubuntu.com/a/291514)

Another solution is to embed a start [script into the head of the archive file](https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable), but it is a bit hacky.
Basically the operating system recognizes the file as a shell script then the script itself calls the `java` command.

For example the [spring-boot plugin is able to make use of this technique](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-install), they embed a script that allows the jar file to be executed directly, as well as working as an init start-stop script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have already installed the binfmt-support and the jar is a+rw, and I have the same error again.

Comment: If you just installed it, I would log out and in again to ensure that it is on the path. Also execute `update-binfmts --display` to see if the java config is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR - That won't work.  Use `java -jar ...`

Setting the execute permissions on a JAR file doesn't make it executable like (say) a native executable file.

On Linux / UNIX / Mac OSX the operating system will look at the first couple of bytes of the file (i.e. the "magic number") to decide what to do when you try to execute it.

- If the first 3 are 'E', 'L', 'F' followed by a version byte, the file is a native executable in ELF format.  The operating system loads it and executes it.
- If the first 3 are '#', '!', '/' followed by root-relative pathname, the file is an executable script.  The pathname tells the OS what script interpreter to use.  The OS starts the interpreter and passes the script pathname to it.
- Other (native) executable files may be recognized by other OS flavors.

In the case of a JAR file, the OS doesn't understand the "magic number" if you try to execute it that way.

---

Note that it typically is NOT the shell that attempts to understand the magic number.  Rather the shell calls the `execve` syscall, passing the filename of the executable and its args and environment variables.  The OS tries to understand the file's magic number, and fails.  The `execve` syscall then returns the `ENOEXEC` error number, which the shell converts to the error message that you saw.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same `invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error` error as you with just the `binfmt-support` package installed.  At least for me, the default for `binfmt-support` was to use `jexec` as the interpreter -- which I think is OpenJDK's -- and that couldn't run my .jar for some reason.

Instead, I was able to use `jarwrapper` (which does depend on `binfmt-support`):

```
sudo apt-get install jarwrapper
```

To see what will be used to intepret your file when you execute it:

```
update-binfmts --find ./batchconverter.jar
```

And to see what binary formats are currently supported:

```
update-binfmts --display
```

Caveat: I have Oracle's Java 10 installed alongside OpenJDK.  I'm not entirely sure if that has any affect on the matter.  I.e. Whether that was a part of the problem or if that makes `jarwrapper` work better?